# openmpi and gfortran error : no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_waitall’

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi, intel-fortran

Fortran code using MPI_Waitall will not compile on my system with gfortran and the openmpi library, but the same code does compile with intel fortran compilers (and the intel mpi implementation). I can't figure out how or why this is happening. Here is a minimal/trivial example of code that fails to compile:

test.f90

```
program TEST_WAITALL

    use MPI

    implicit none

    integer :: ierr
    integer :: N
    integer, allocatable :: reqs(:)
    integer :: to, tag, count
    double precision :: data(100) 

    N = 5
    reqs = 1

    call MPI_INIT( ierr )
    call MPI_Waitall(N, reqs, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    call MPI_SEND( data, count, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, to, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )
    call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )

end program TEST_WAITALL
```

Note this is not intended to run, and is clearly "nonsense" code.

When I compile with the intel toolchain, there are no issues:

```
mpiifort test.f90
```

When I compile with the gfortran/openmpi toolchain I get an error:

```
mpifort test.f90
test.f90:17:54:

     call MPI_Waitall(N, reqs, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
                                                      1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_waitall’ at (1)
```

If I comment out just the call to MPI_Waitall, then the code compiles with both gfortran/openmpi and intel. So MPI is being found and linked against.

My first guess would be that somehow I've used the wrong interface to MPI_Waitall, and that I'm trying to pass arguments of the wrong type, but as far as I can see from online documentation, I can't see any problems with types.

I've also changed the third argument from an array of statuses to MPI_STATUS_IGNORE to see if this fixes the problem, but it did not.

I have openmpi-bin installed through the package manager (apt) on ubuntu, and compiler info is as follows:

```
mpifort -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Comment: you have to use `MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE` and **not** `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`

Comment: "I've also changed the third argument from an array of statuses to MPI_STATUS_IGNORE to see if this fixes the problem, but it did not." The above comment and VladimirF's answer address the case of MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, but can you show us what you wrote with the array of statuses - that should also work.

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet, you're 100% correct. Unfortunately, the error in my code was a different to the one in the simple example (purely my mistake). Whilst reducing to a minimal example, I lost the real error in the simplification and picked up another! In the real code I was passing a non-contiguous array as MPI_Waitall second argument. openmpi didn't like this but Intel fortran seems to handle it.

Comment: Can you please post a [MCVE] with the initial error ? That could indicate a bug in Open MPI or Intel MPI (MPICH based)

Comment: I can reproduce this with the above code by changing the waitall call to `call MPI_Waitall(N, reqs(selection), MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE, ierr)` and adding a a variable declaration `integer, allocatable :: selection(:)`. This compiles with intel but not openmpi.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE and not MPI_STATUS_IGNORE because it is multiple statuses, each for each request.